# withUnsafeBytes + Generic type behavior

Tags: swift, pointers, generics

I have a function that allows me to read a number (Integer, Double etc) from a binary file using generic types. For example if I expect a `Int64`, il will read 8 bytes...

```
// A simple function that read n bytes from a FileHandle and returns
// the data

public func read(chunkSize: Int) -> Data {
   return self.handle!.readData(ofLength: chunkSize)
}

// A function that reads the proper amount of bytes specified
// by the return type which in my case would be an integer 

public func readNumber<I>() -> I? {
   let data: Data = self.read(chunkSize: MemoryLayout<I>.size)
   if data.count == 0 {
       return nil
   }
   return data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
}
```

The `readNumber` randomly returns nil for no reason. Not from the `count` check but from the last line.

However it perfectly works when I cast to `I` like so :

`return data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee } as I`

Why is that ?

**EDIT:**

I reproduced this using Playgrounds :

```
class Test {

    public func read(chunkSize: Int) -> Data {
        return Data(repeating: 1, count: chunkSize)
    }

    public func readNumber<T>() -> T? {
        let data: Data = read(chunkSize: MemoryLayout<T>.size)
        if data.count == 0 {
            return nil
        }
        return data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
    }

    public func example() {
        let value2: Double = readNumber()!
        print(value2)
    }
}

let test = Test()

for i in 0..<1000 {
    test.example()
}
```

Comment: Generics and type inference show sometimes weird behavior, but as far as I have experienced till now, it have never shown something _randomly_. Generally, Swift infers the type `I` as you do not expect. For example, `I` can be `Optional<Int>` in some cases.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. You shouldn't need `handle` to make this work; you can just return `Data(repeating: 1, count: chunkSize)` in `read`. Given that, can you build a small example that demonstrates the problem? I strongly suspect the issue is in your calling side, because you're specializing based on the return type (which is very awkward), and you haven't constrained the return type at all (not even to `FixedWidthInteger`).

Comment: I am using a handle because in my case I deal with files, I just pasted the function but yes technically it should also happen with a Data object not coming out of a handle read.
I removed the `<I: FixedWidthInteger>` because I had to read also `Double` values, but did not really know what protocol to put in.

Comment: @RobNapier Everytime it returned nil and failed, was when I was expecting a Double value. If this gives you a hint ?
Also, you think it's awkward to use generics from return types as I did ? Even when providing info about the generic itself such as `FixedWidthInteger`?

Comment: @RobNapier I can reproduce the issue using Playgrounds and without a `FileHandle`, let me update my question. Also it doesn't crash everytime. You will see that I repeat the read 1000 times because in my real project we read a significant amount of bytes

Comment: Oh, it crashes! (You said it returned `nil` which is not the same thing.) That explains the problem.

Comment: It crashes because it returns nil.  This is how I know it returns nil, because I put a `!` after my `readNumber()` call

Comment: I don't know if it's really nil or just invalid memory. As Alexander noted, this you're returning UB data.

Comment: @RobNapier mhmm, weird... But I don't get how adding the `as I` solves the issues

Comment: Because that forces a copy to be made. It is unfortunate in Swift that is not always clear whether `as` is just reevaluating memory or is copying memory. In this case it's copying it.

Comment: @RobNapier so if I understand, that would pretty much be the same as declaring a variable, storing the value inside and returning it right ?
Also, UB stands for Unsafe Bytes ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183225/discussion-between-scaraux-and-rob-napier).

Comment: Worth noting that `withUnsafeBytes(_:)` is [a fundamentally broken API](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-use-data-withunsafebytes-in-a-well-defined-manner/12811), and I would avoid using it until it's replaced by a version that gives you a raw pointer instead of a typed pointer ([hopefully this will happen soon](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/20225)). Also bear in mind that you're assuming the endianness of the data matches the endianness of your platform. All in all, I would [consider using bit shifts instead](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/0abcb35270878f22f223a3aad4977020).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems I need to correct my comment a little. Even when Swift works consistently as programmed, the result may seem randomly changing, when you have some memory issue like accessing out of bounds.

First prepare a magical extension for `UnsafePointer`:

```
extension UnsafePointer {
    var printingPointee: Pointee {
        print(Pointee.self) //<- Check how Swift inferred `Pointee`
        return self.pointee
    }
}
```

And modify your **EDIT** code a little:

```
class Test {

    public func read(chunkSize: Int) -> Data {
        return Data(repeating: 1, count: chunkSize)
    }

    public func readNumber<T>() -> T? {
        let data: Data = read(chunkSize: MemoryLayout<T>.size)
        if data.count == 0 {
            return nil
        }
        print(T.self) //<- Check how Swift inferred `T`
        return data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.printingPointee }
    }

    public func example() {
        let value2: Double = readNumber()!
        print(value2)
    }
}

let test = Test()

for _ in 0..<1000 {
    test.example()
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Double
> Optional<Double>
> 7.748604185489348e-304
> Double
> Optional<Double>
> ```
>
> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

How many pairs of `Double` and `Optional<Double>` shown would be seemingly random, but the cause of this behavior is quite clear.

In this line `return data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.printingPointee }`, Swift infers the type of `$0` as `UnsafePointer<Optional<Double>>`.

In the current implementation of Swift, `Optional<Double>` occupies 9 bytes in memory:

```
print(MemoryLayout<Optional<Double>>.size) //-> 9
```

So, `$0.pointee` accesses 9 bytes starting from the pointer, although the pointer is pointing to the region of 8-byte:

```
|+0|+1|+2|+3|+4|+5|+6|+7|+8|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 ??
 <-taken from the Data->
```

As you know, the extra 9th (`+8`) byte cannot be predictable and may seemingly be random, which is an indicator of `nil` in `Optional<Double>`.

Exactly the same inference is working in your code. In your `readNumber<T>()`, the return type is clearly declared as `T?`, so, in the line `return data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }`, it is very natural that Swift infers the type of `$0.pointee` as `Double?` aka `Optional<Double>`.

You know you can control this type inference with adding `as T`.